# How can I set a time between slides to create an automatic slideshow with beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I switched from PowerPoint to Beamer. I developed my presentation in Beamer and would like to create a slide show that will play my file automatically.  Is there a way to set a time between slide as we can do in a PowerPoint slideshow?

Comment: You can set this in at least some PDF viewers. For example in Adobe Reader X, there is a checkbox in Edit --> Preferences --> Fullscreen for moving forward one page every *n* seconds.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `\transduration` command for this (page 142 of the [manual](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)):

> `\transduration<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨number of seconds⟩}` In full
>   screen mode, show the slide for `⟨number of seconds⟩`. If zero is
>   specified, the slide is shown as short as possible. This can be used
>   to create interesting pseudo-animations. Example: `\transduration<2>{1}`

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\transduration{0.75}
This is my first frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\transduration{0.75}
This is my second frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\transduration{0.75}
This is my third frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

output - [image]
I use `convert -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 file.pdf file.gif` to make gif.

Comment: (+1) @Thorsten: Great. Much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does it work with evince or only with acroread ?

Comment: @Tarass it works in evince also.

Comment: @Thorsten if you also gave turn off autotransition solution without removing each `\transduration` line, it would useful.

Comment: Is there any way to loop back into the first slide (without resorting to the creation of a gif file)?

Comment: Is there a way to set `\transduration` (or its variants such as \transdissolve) for all frames globally. This could come in handy. I couldn't find a way to do this in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try the [Impress!ve PDF viewer](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/), which gives numerous functionalities dedicated to  presentations (and of course, fine timing of slides).

Note: this is not a "pure" `beamer` solution since to have the full usage of impressive power you will have to define a script associated with your PDF file. Well, in other words, you can also consider that this is a PDF-origin independent solution.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for. Nevertheless, this may be a solution for less formal presentations.