# Is possible to temporize overlays in beamer?

Tags: beamer, overlays

Consider this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 16pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[titleformat=smallcaps]{metropolis} % Usemetropolistheme

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[standout]
\only<+>{H}
\only<+>{He}
\only<+>{Hel}
\only<+>{Hell}
\only<+>{Hello}
\only<+>{Hello w}
\only<+>{Hello wo}
\only<+>{Hello wor}
\only<+>{Hello worl}
\only<+>{Hello world}
\only<+>{Hello world!}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Basically, it's animated text using beamer's overlay. However, as far as I know, I have to manually go to the next slide to make it works. There is a way to temporize the process? I know that a solution could be to export the image, make a gif and use the animate package. However there are two downsides in this solution: gifs are not vectorial, I have to make a new gif each time I change something in the layout (like fonts or anything like that).

**Note** It's not mandatory to use beamer overlays. However, the solution must work with beamer class and xelatex compiler.

Comment: The `animate` way does not require the detour via GIF. Where did you get this information from? Pkg `animate` is perfectly suited for animating vectorial graphics within PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the time each overlay should be shown with `\transduration{<time in seconds>}`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[standout]
\transduration{0.1}
\only<+>{H}
\only<+>{He}
\only<+>{Hel}
\only<+>{Hell}
\only<+>{Hello}
\only<+>{Hello w}
\only<+>{Hello wo}
\only<+>{Hello wor}
\only<+>{Hello worl}
\only<+>{Hello world}
\only<+>{Hello world!}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the automatic slide transitions only work with pdf viewers that support java script and they need to be in presentation mode.

Comment: It works. and the result is the same as using `\animate<>`. However, with both of them slides changes each second. There is a problem in my pdf viewer?

Comment: @gvgramazio Which pdfviewer do you use? With the example above they should change ten times a second. (if the slides are complex and/or the computer is slow, rendering can take longer)

Comment: The default document viewer of Ubuntu 18.04: Evince 3.28.4

Comment: And it doesn't work at all with the integrated pdf viewer of Firefox.

Comment: @gvgramazio Can you try with adobe reader?

Comment: It's not developed anymore for Linux. The last version dates back in 2013.

Comment: @gvgramazio https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40332/how-can-i-set-a-time-between-slides-to-create-an-automatic-slideshow-with-beamer#comment971330_40335 suggests that it also works in evince

Comment: `\transduration{3}` works fine with evince. The problem is for small transitions.

Comment: @gvgramazio The problem might then be the time necessary to render the slide, even a `\transduration{0}` will only be as fast as the rendering is done

Comment: If I move through slides with keys I scroll the whole presentation (roughly 50 slides) in 2 seconds or so. I don't think the problem is the rendering. Maybe the time resolution in evince is low.

Comment: Anyway, your answer solve my question so it deserves to be accepted. I just need to solve another problem now. :)

Comment: I confirm that the problem doesn't exist with okular.

Comment: @gvgramazio If you are really desperate, produce an animated gif as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799) or an mp4 as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462207/121799), and embed them. Needless to say that will reduce the quality, and whether there is a way to synchronize the resolution with the one of the projector I don't know.

Comment: @gvgramazio What makes you think `animate` would need a gif sequence as input?

Comment: @AlexG my bad, I mixed up things.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clear up the misunderstanding that an `animate`-based solution would require a pre-fabricated set of bitmapped (gif, png, whatever) animation frames. Of course, a JavaScript supporting PDF viewer is required for this kind of animations; on Linux there is at least Okular that provides this functionality, besides Acrobat Reader for the other platforms.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,16pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[titleformat=smallcaps]{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[standout]

  \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut H} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut He} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hel} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hell} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hello} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hello w} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hello wo} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hello wor} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hello worl} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hello world} \newframe  
    \makebox[\widthof{\strut Hello world!}][l]{\strut Hello world!}
  \end{animateinline}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Click on the image to see the animated version (vectorial [SVG]):

[image]