# Automate transition on slides using Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, beamer-metropolis

I have multiple images that I would like to show on a single slide in `beamer`. These images are in fact related and I would like to simulate a GIF by transitioning between these images.

Currently, I am using the `\only<1>{}` command to show image 1, `\only<2>` to show image 2 etc. and relying on manually progressing to see the next image. Is there a way to automatically transition between these images on the same slide with a specified transition time?

I am using `beamer-metropolis`. Consider the following MWE, where the 'images' are simple TikZ lines:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\only<1>{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw[line width=2.5pt] (0,-2) to[out=0,in=135] (14, -9) to[out=315,in=125] (20,-16);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\only<2>{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw [line width=2.5pt] (-14,-9) to [out=45,in=180] (0,-2) to[out=0,in=135] (14, -9) to[out=315,in=125] (20,-16);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\only<3>{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw [line width=2.5pt] (-19.5,-16) to[out=55,in=228] (-14,-9) to [out=45,in=180] (0,-2) to[out=0,in=135] (14, -9) to[out=315,in=125] (20,-16);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I have seen related posts on stack exchange for examples and the beamer manual, but with no effect on transition times for slides.

Even when trying the following MWE (Thorsten's answer from [How can I set a time between slides to create an automatic slideshow with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40332/how-can-i-set-a-time-between-slides-to-create-an-automatic-slideshow-with-beamer/40335#40335)):

```
\begin{frame}
\transduration{0.75}
This is my first frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\transduration{0.75}
This is my second frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\transduration{0.75}
This is my third frame
\end{frame}
```

I get no effect when I view the slides in my pdf viewer (Acrobat and Preview).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40335/161015

Comment: This kind of animation requires the FullScreen/Presentation mode of the PDF viewer.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try the `animate` package and use the `autoplay` option together with a suitable frame rate. This works in Acrobat Reader and  Okular.